# How to change type of int to double in c++

Tags: c++, types, numbers, primitive-types

Is there any way to initialize a variable as a general number type or int and then change its type to double for example?

```
TYPE x = 4;
// commands changing its type
here it(variable x) became double.
```

I know it is weird.

The variable has to have the same name.

Comment: maybe `#define x 4; double d = x;` ?

Comment: You can't have two variables with the same name. And you can't have a variable of two types. And a `union` wouldn't work since the bit patterns of an `int` are different from a `double`; assigning in one type and reading as a different type will end in tears.

Comment: There's no such thing as a "double int". Type `double` is a floating-point type; `int` is an integer type.  There's type `long int`, which is an integer type that *may or may not* be twice the width of `int`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No. C++ is a statically typed languages. The type is fixed when the variable is declared.

You could kind of do what you describe using a union, but great care is required, e.g.

```
union DoubleInt
{
  int i;
  double d;
};

DoubleInt X;
X.i = 4;

// ... whatever

X.d = X.i;
X.d += 0.25;
```

But unions are really only a sensible option where you're desperate to bit pack. You could also create a class that can behave as either a double or int but, really, what you're talking about doing doesn't sound like you're thinking in a C++ way.

Finally, [boost::variant](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/variant.html) might do what you want?

Comment: Indeed (+1). You probably should not want to change the type of a variable at run-time. Consider changing your design?

Comment: I wouldn't suggest a union. That merely reinterprets the bit pattern. Not what the OP wants.

Comment: I wouldn't suggest a union, either, but it *might* do what the OP wants, I'm not clear what they want or why.

Comment: @JackAidley, the OP want's the type to change, but the value to remain correct. `x = 3` becomse `x = 3.0`. I think your class suggestion is the only way to go.

Comment: @StoryTeller: A union *doesn't* reinterpret the bit pattern (in fact, trying to use a union to do this will invoke undefined behaviour). A union allows two objects to share an address (with a single active object at a time).

Comment: @StoryTeller: I think you're probably right about that, although they don't say, which is why I stuck the `X.d = X.i` line in. The probable correct answer is: don't do that.

Comment: Well we need to know what the OP wants here. I don't see why they wouldn't just store it as a double in the first place unless they are trying to create a dynamic type.

Comment: @Mankarse, when you read a union member that you didn't initialize explicitly, the result is undefined I agree. But the garbage does depend on the last active object, and it's bit pattern. I agree that depending on that "reinterpretation" is relying on undefined behavior. I should have been more precise.

Comment: Ah, yes. boost::variant. +1 :)

Comment: @StoryTeller: Notice that Jack Aidley is always initialising/activating the `union` members before reading from them. There is no bit-pattern reinterpretation in this code, and nor should there be in any reasonable code containing `union`s.

Comment: @Mankarse, The example was added as I wrote my comment, and I already agreed with you. Stop beating a dead horse :)

Answer (score 2):

Though it is not possible to change the type of a variable, you can define a type capable of representing variables of *various* types. This is generally called a *variant*. Go and get [Boost.Variant](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/variant.html) which allows you to write code like this:

```
boost::variant<int, double> t_either_int_or_double;

t_either_int_or_double = 1;

// now it is "int"
assert(boost::get<int>(t_either_int_or_double);

t_either_int_or_double = 1.0;

// now it is "double"
assert(boost::get<double>(t_either_int_or_double);
```